# 2 similar Modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am sort of new to javascript. Right now I am working on a project that will allow users to add and remove parks from my website. For this, I want to have a popup window that will allow them to enter a state and park name to either add or remove. I am trying to add 2 modals, one for adding, one for removing. However, because I am doing it in 2 separate js files, only remove is being called, and it is being called for both of them.

Here is some of my html

```
<body id="page-dash" class="container">
    <div class="one">
        <ul class="vertical">
            <li id="addBtn" class="vertical"><a href="#">Add a Park</a><br></li>
            <li id="remBtn" class="vertical"><a href="#">Remove a Park</a><br></li>
            <li id="updateBtn" class="vertical"><a href="#">Update List</a><br></li>
            <li id="passBtn" class="vertical"><a href="#">Reset Password</a><br></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="stateParkList" class="two">
        <p id="desc">List of states and their National Parks.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Pop Up Window -->
    <div id="addWindow">
    <div id="popUp-add" class="popUp">
        <div class="popUp-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <form id="Form">
                <p>Add Park</p><br>
                <p>State:</p>
                <input type="text" id="state"><br>
                <p>National Park:</p>
                <input type="text" id="park"><br>
                <button onclick="addPark()">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="remWindow">
    <div id="popUp-rem" class="popUp">
        <div class="popUp-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <form id="Form">
                <p>Remove Park</p><br>
                <p>State:</p>
                <input type="text" id="state"><br>
                <p>National Park:</p>
                <input type="text" id="park"><br>
                <button onclick="remPark()">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

    <footer>&copy; Copyright CS234-SIUe-Spring 17. All rights reserved.</footer>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/parks.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/add.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/remove.js"></script>
```

Here is the add.js:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('popUp-add');

var btn = document.getElementById("addBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

the remove.js:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('popUp-rem');

var btn = document.getElementById("remBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

and CSS:

```
/*Pop up window in dashboard*/
.popUp {
    display: none; 
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.popUp-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 15%;
    height: 23%;
    font-size: 18px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: -7%;
    margin-right: -5%;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

form#Form input{
    border: 1pt solid black;
}
form#Form input{
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce your code on jsbin.com?

Comment: "*However, because I am doing it in 2 separate js files, only remove is being called, and it is being called for both of them.*" ...more detail please.

Comment: Also... "*CS234-SIUe-Spring 17*" ...this looks like homework. Make sure to review this post about homework questions: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Yes this is homework, it is a specific problem, and i have sunken an hour and half into this one problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two problems.

1. You define all your varables in global(window) scopes and it result in unexpected changes. In `add.js` three varables `modal`,`btn` and `span` are defined which is exactly the same in `remove.js`.Because you load `remove.js` later,the actual value of the three varables is the later assignment in `remove.js`

   ```
   var modal = document.getElementById('popUp-rem');
   var btn = document.getElementById("remBtn");
   var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
   ```

   You can use [function scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) and [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to avoid global namespace polution
2. You should use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) rather than `onclick` when you need to add multiple event to the same dom element,in this case are `window` and `span`.Because binding event by `onclick` would be overwrite after newer assignment.Therefore `onclick` would only response to the latest function,in this case only functions in `remove.js` is being called.

You should change your code like this

add.js

```
 (function() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('popUp-add');

    var btn = document.getElementById("addBtn");

    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    span.addEventListener('click',function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    })

    window.addEventListener('click',function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    })
})()
```

remove.js

```
 (function() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('popUp-rem');

    var btn = document.getElementById("remBtn");

    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    span.addEventListener('click',function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    })

    window.addEventListener('click',function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    })
})()
```

One more thing,if your website need to be compatible for IE,consider using [attachEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/attachEvent) instead.